# How to Change select dropdown value while selecting downdown 1?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the db called rec where i store records like:

```
Id  Name Surname

1   John smith
2   Roger jhonson
```

I wish to display all records in 2 drop-down menus. Say if I select Roger then the value of surname should be changed to Jhonson if it was already on Smith.

If I select John then value of the surname should go back to smith but if I want I should be able to change the surname of John to Jhonson which should not change the value of **Name**, the selected value should remain as John Jhonson.

Can someone please show me how this can be done?

Really appreciate your kind help and time in advance.

Comment: A sample of the code you're working with would be helpful, but if you can get a string value of a select and assign it to a var named text (let's say) you can work with something like text.replace("Smith", "Johnson"); and wise verse.

Comment: There are many questions about cascading dropdowns that show how to change one dropdown when the user selects from another.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: Look for `dependent dropdown list` it will help you understand the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select name="cname" class="float-right ralign" id="cname">
            <option value="" disabled selected>--select name--</option>
            <option value="1">John</option>
            <option value="2">Roger</option>
          </select>

             <select name="surname" class="float-right ralign" id="surname">
            <option value="" disabled selected>--select surname--</option>
            <option value="1">smith</option>
            <option value="2">jhonson</option>
          </select>
```

Use jQuery `Onchange` Event

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function(){


    $("#cname").change(function(){
        var cname = $(this).val();
        $('#surname option').eq(cname).prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){

 $("#cname").change(function(){
  var cname = $(this).val();
  $('#surname option').eq(cname).prop('selected', true);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cname" class="float-right ralign" id="cname">
            <option value="" disabled selected>--select name--</option>
            <option value="1">John</option>
            <option value="2">Roger</option>
          </select>

    <select name="surname" class="float-right ralign" id="surname">
            <option value="" disabled selected>--select surname--</option>
            <option value="1">smith</option>
            <option value="2">jhonson</option>
          </select>
```